# Rephrase "come + doing something"

Tags: verbs

I often come across sentences like this: The children came running into the room.

I know that the following sentences mean the same thing, but I wonder which of the following the original one is grammatically equivalent to.

> The children came, running into the room.
>
> The children came into the room, running.

Comment: That would be the second one. Actually the first alternative does _not_ mean the same thing.

Comment: I also prefer the sencond one, but what is the difference here?

Comment: "The child came, running into the room" means that the child came, while it was running into the room. It does not mean the child came _into_ to room. Actually, "the child came" is a pretty weird sentence on its own, you would have to know from context what the meaning is. "Did Johnny visit you at all? Yes he came yesterday. (Running into the room???)".

Comment: With the comma, there's nothing special about the verb _come_ in this structure. Essentially, the second part clarifies how the first part happened: _The children left, laughing about the joke. The parents drove to Detroit, worrying about their daughter. The churchgoers sang, lifting their hands toward heaven. The protesters marched, chanting slogans of discontent. The children came for a visit, running in through the front door._

Comment: What is the semantic difference without the comma? The second part of your examples defines in what way the main verbs are carried out. @J.R.♦

Comment: @J.R.: I just feel some semantic grating at "they came, running into the room". But the sentence _could_ make sense, I suppose.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng: Without the comma, they _came into the room_, in a _running_ way. With the comma, they _came_, while _running into the room_.

Comment: If I removed the commas, I think those sentences would read very awkwardly. I would probably rephrase all of them: _The children left while laughing about the joke. The parents drove to Detroit as they worried about their daughter. The churchgoers sang and lifted their hands toward heaven. The protesters marched while they chanted slogans of discontent. The children came for a visit and ran in through the front door._ Those commas are doing more than indicating a pause.

Comment: Can I rephrase "The children came for a visit, running in through the front door." to "The children came running in through the front door for a visit"? @J.R.♦

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To 'come running' can (sort of) be considered a shortening of two actions:

> The children came into the room.
>
> The children were running.

You can shorten these two states to:

> The children came running into the room.

Both of the statements you wrote there mean roughly the same as 'to come running', though the second one is more natural to say.